# How to parse json url using android?

Tags: android

I want parse json url,my json url contains following structures

```
{"content":{"item":[{"category":"xxx"},{"category":"yy"} ]}}
```

how to read this structure,anybody knows give example json parser for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you to parse yours json.

```
 String jsonStr = "{\"content\":{\"item\":[{\"category\":\"xxx\"},{\"category\":\"yy\"} ]}}";
 try {
        ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONObject content = obj.getJSONObject("content");
        JSONArray array = content.getJSONArray("item");
        for(int i = 0, count = array.length();i<count;i++)
        {
            JSONObject categoty = array.getJSONObject(i);
            categories.add(categoty.getString("category"));
        }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) can do the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)'s package.
Example:

For an object:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json_string);
```

For an array:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(json_string);
```